# Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.4.0

Tags: android

[please What is the solution to this problem 
Android Studio 3.1.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfZjE.png)

Comment: Maybe this help. [Gradle build version](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin "here") I think you want to include Gradle version 4.4.0. But this statement `com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.X.X` you should include Gradle plugin version instead of Gradle version which is **3.1.2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `com.android.tools.build` having **version** `4.4.0`. Latest **version** is `3.1.2`. Change it to `3.1.2` and try to sync

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
}
```

> Note : Make sure you are connected to internet.